# check if const char * is zero terminated

Tags: c, char

I am working on a library.
I have a `const char *` that is supposed to be zero terminated as an input, however for some reason it is not always zero terminated.

Whenever it is not zero terminated undefined behavior invoked - sometimes also crash.

Despite it is a matter of the wrong input -- I don't want to crash so:

My question: Is there any way to know if the `const char *` is zero terminated? or Not zero terminated ? (I don't get the length of `const char *` as an input).

P.S. Well I have figured out that there is a way to know when it is not zero terminated -> I crashing :-)
I would like to figure that out before the crash :)

Comment: A pointer cannot be "null terminated" (whatever that would mean).

Comment: It's not `NULL` terminated, it's the ascii `nul`. No, you can't figure it out because the only way to know for sure is to search for the `nul` character and if it's absent then surely will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Please read about pointers, _null pointers_, the **macro** `NULL` and "strings" in C. These are very basic concepts. You will not be able to use C correctly without understanding these concepts.

Comment: `strchr(example, '\n') != NULL`, but that will not cause undefined behavior. The absent `nul` on the other hand is surely a problem.

Comment: This is the case with many inbuilt library functions as they expect the string passed to be nul terminated without which it crashes. So care should be taken before passing parameters to your function

Comment: @user3351949: Your title says "null terminated", but the question now says "`\n` terminated". Which is it? And (if it's `\n`) does the string have a `NUL` (zero) byte at the end?

Comment: In C "strings" are just convention. Not following that convention invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of a null-terminated string is to put the `\0` as the last character in order to mark the end of the string and thus have a way to determine the end of the character array.

If you don't know the length of the string and don't have anything in the content of the string to determine its length (e.g. a terminator character such as `\0`) then you can't access it without risking reading out of its allocated memory.

Accessing data outside of an allocated memory block is undefined behavior in C and there's nothing you can do to prevent a possible crash. If your library's function is documeted to take a null-terminated string as an input, **it's the user responsibility to give you a proper input**, not your fault if you crash otherwise.

Note as a reference that all proper C string is supposed to be a null-terminated character array and all standard string manipulation functions defined in `string.h` (`strcpy`, `strcmp`, etc.) will behave the same way if called with anything other than a proper null-terminated string.